# Integer pointer only has correct value if I print it

Tags: c++, pointers

I am implementing my own smart_pointer, which counts the references to the thing it points to. Here is my implementation so far:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class smart_pointer{
    T* pointer;
    int* cnt;
public:
    smart_pointer<T>(T *el): pointer(el) { int i = 1; cnt = &i; }; // 
     smart_pointer<T>(const smart_pointer<T>& other): pointer(other.pointer) { 
        // std::cout << ", *(other.cnt): " << *(other.cnt);
        cnt = other.cnt;
        (*cnt)++; 
    } // Copy-constructor

    int counter(){ 
        int c = *cnt;
        return c; 
    }
};
```

In main.cpp, I did the following:

```cpp
int main(){
    // smart_pointer_examples();
    std::string h("hello");
    smart_pointer<std::string> p(&h);
    std::cout << "p: " << p.counter();
    smart_pointer<std::string> q(p);
    std::cout << ", q: " << q.counter() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that that outputs `p: 1, q: 6487781`. After a lot of time trying to find the issue by debugging and printing stuff, I found something that fixed my issue: By adding `std::cout << ", *(other.cnt): " << *(other.cnt);` somewhere in my copy-constructor, the output becomes `p: 1, *(other.cnt): 1, q: 2`, which is the desired behaviour. I can't for the life of me think of why printing the counter would change anything.

Edit: Also, if I only do `*(other.cnt)` without std::cout, the same problem that I started with happens.

Comment: `int * count; ` is totally unnecessary. Do `int count;` instead. Looks like you have got a lot basics to cover before you can attempt something like this.

Comment: `int i = 1; cnt = &i;` You've taken the address of the local variable `i` and store the address in `cnt`, but this address of `i` is only valid when the constructor is running. This is a sign that you need to go through some basics of C++.

Comment: Because it is designed to store pointers to objects with automatic storage duration this smart pointer is doomed to fail.

Comment: "I am implementing my own smart_pointer" - Why oh *why*? Don't do that - use the standard ones handed to you by the standard library. You can only do worse by trying to implement them yourself.

Comment: @Lance How would you do the following scenario without cnt being a pointer: You have some object o1. You create a smart pointer to it(`smart_pointer<Object> p`). Then you create another smart pointer to p, which means also to o1 (`smart_pointer<Object> q(p)`). Now, both p and q should have a counter of 2. But once you delete either p or q, the other one should have a counter of one again.

Comment: you seem to be trying to implement std lib shared pointer, in which case the data pointer and the use count need to be in a shared memory block that the smart pointer instances point to.

Comment: @JesperJuhl For practice with cpp and pointers, which as confirmed by Lance I need a lot of. It's an assignment I have to do for University.

Comment: perhaps implement unique pointer first - if you  want an exercise with pointers, try implementing std::vector

Comment: @Marc Miller take a look at shared_ptr implementation for inspiration. I would suggested something like `struct msp_core{ void * ptr=nullptr; int refcount=0; }; template<class T> class my_shared_ptr{...private: msp_core * data; }; ` and you start from here.

Comment: you don't seem to understand what a shared pointer is for - at the end of its life a shared pointer should delete the data pointer if the shared pointed-to count is zero. if the thing the pointed to was not allocated with new, the shared pointer will just cause UB

Comment: @MarcMiller - The "fix" doesn't really work. When you have two pointer objects, and the first one is deleted, you again have a dangling pointer. The real `shared_ptr` has the counter in a separately allocated control block that is used by all copies.

Answer (score 2):

You made a small mistake in implementing your idea.

I will not comment on the design of your smart pointer implementation.

The problem is that you implemented your counter as a pointer. That is wrong.

And, you are dereferencing a local variable. That is a semantic bug. The result is undefined. The value of the counter will be indeterminate. Additionally you should initialize your class members.

If we fix both, then your code will look like:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class smart_pointer {
    T* pointer{};
    int cnt{};
public:
    smart_pointer<T>(T* el) : pointer(el) { cnt = 1; }; // 
    smart_pointer<T>(const smart_pointer<T>& other) : pointer(other.pointer) {
        // std::cout << ", *(other.cnt): " << *(other.cnt);
        cnt = other.cnt;
        cnt++;
    } // Copy-constructor

    int counter() const {
        return cnt;
    }
};
int main() {
    // smart_pointer_examples();
    std::string h("hello");
    smart_pointer<std::string> p(&h);
    std::cout << "p: " << p.counter();
    smart_pointer<std::string> q(p);
    std::cout << ", q: " << q.counter() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason I tried implementing with pointers is that once a smart_pointer is destroyed, in its destructor I can do `--(*cnt)` before destroying it. That way, all other smart_pointers created with the copy constructor would get "updated" about one less smart_pointer pointing to their object. I left this out of my question, but I see that that was an important piece of information.

Comment: @Marc how do the other smart pointers get get notified?

Comment: Well the idea was that a smart_pointer is either created by pointing to new object (so count=1) or by passing another smart_pointer. In that case, I would take the address of the counter of that pointer, so that I could increment it from my new pointer. Then both smart_pointers would have pointers to the same cnt integer in memory, and they could both update it. Many people said that using pointers for this is a bad idea, but I honestly don't know why. To me, it seems like the perfect use-case for pointers since multiple objects need to access & modify one integer.

Comment: @NeilButterworth and Armin: Please see my updated question for how I managed to solve my issue. I'm still interested in why I had the problem I described only when I didn't include the `cout << *(other.cnt)` and I would also like to hear about your opinions regarding my "solution".

Answer (score 1):

Your basic Problem is that you are storing a pointer to a local variable `i`. That variable goes out of scope and the pointer becomes invalid and reading from it triggers undefined behaviour.

The solution it to just create an object with dynamic storage, e.g. via `operator new`.

```
// Wrong:
{ int i = 1; cnt = &i; };
// Correct:
{ cnt = new int(1); }
```

Despite what the other answer says, the counter must not be stored directly inside the smart pointer. Multiple instances of `smart_pointer` must be able to use the very same counter object, the counter must be shared among them.

Storing the counter directly in the `smart_pointer` means it can be incremented in one instance, without any other instance noticing it. You'll have two instances, one that has counter=1 and one that has counter=2, the first one does not know that the pointer is also stored in another `smart_pointer`.

Here is a more complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

// Testing class that explicitly shows when instancess of get created and when isntances of it are destroyed.
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "Creating Foo at " << static_cast<void*>(this) << "\n";
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "Destroying Foo at " << static_cast<void*>(this) << "\n";
    }
};

template <typename T>
class smart_pointer{
    T* pointer;
    int* cnt;

public:
    smart_pointer(T *el)
    : pointer(el)
    , cnt(new int(1))
    {
    }
    smart_pointer(const smart_pointer& other)
    : pointer(other.pointer)
    , cnt(other.cnt)
    {
        (*cnt)++;
    }
    ~smart_pointer() {
        (*cnt)--;
        if(*cnt == 0) {
            delete cnt;
            delete pointer;
        }
    }
    int counter(){ 
         return *cnt;
    }
};

int main(){
    smart_pointer<Foo> p(new Foo());
    std::cout << "p: " << p.counter();
    smart_pointer<Foo> q(p);
    std::cout << ", q: " << q.counter() << std::endl;
    // Note that p.counter() is now also 2, not 1
    std::cout << "p: " << p.counter() << std::endl;
}
```

Output from https://godbolt.org/ :

```
Creating Foo at 0xd452b0
p: 1, q: 2
p: 2
Destroying Foo at 0xd452b0
```